# AWS Lambda + DynamoDB Invalid security token in request

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Lambda function that connects with DynamoDB. If I build and deploy this function and run it in my AWS console it works just fine, but if I try to execute it from my IDE (Intellij) it doesn't work. I get the following error message:

```
The security token included in the request is invalid (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException;
```

I tried looking at other questions here and nothing seems to workout. I have two users and each one has one group. One of them has AdministratorAcces and the other has DynamoDBFullAccess and AWSLambda_FullAccess permissions. None of them can execute the function locally. Tried to reconfigure my credentials using `aws configure` in cmd.

I also tried to create new security credentials. And the problem is not with the function because if I remove the DynamoDB connection code and run and deploy locally the function or deploy it in my AWS console successfuly executes. Anyway I will post below the code of my connection:

```
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

    MyCustomData data = new MyCustomData("test","12313","test2");
    mapper.save(data);
```

EDIT:

I've been debuging the code where the exact problem occurs and seems that in the class `AmazonHttpCLient.java` there is a part that checks the credentials. The point is that there are three properties in the `AWSCredentials` object:
[image]

My credentials in the ~/.aws/credentials doesn't have a sessionToken parameter, and I at any moment seted that. Also a friend of mine debuged the same project and said that there is no property `sessionToken` in his debug. I tried to reinstall AWS CLI, SAM and Intellij, deleted the credentials files and checked if there is no credentials in my variables environment but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by downgrading my SAM CLI version. It was in 1.15.0 and my friends was in 1.6.2. So I downloaded that specific version and worked like a charm.

I don't know why this happens but I hope this gets fixed in in future versions.

I hope it helps someone having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, this error is due to the credentials/aws profile used for establishing connection with AWS account.

To troubleshoot this issue using IntelliJ IDEA, I would suggest you to install [AWS Toolkit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/setup-toolkit.html#eap-or-custom-install) into your IntelliJ IDEA. Furthermore, use AWS Toolkit to find out which aws profile to use to meet your use-case.

otherwise, refer this existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800742/dynamodb-the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-invalid-unrecognizedclien) for more other option

Comment: Thanks, amitd. Acctually I'm already using AWS Toolkit on Intellij. I've also have read the thread before and checked the solutions but nothing seems to work. There was credentials seted in the environment variables, but even after removing then it seems like the function cannot reach the credentials file. For me the only thing that work is to put the credentials in code, but that is a bad practice.